# NSDecimalNumber, addition, and just not sure

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not sure what to do next. They're just dollar amounts from a text field. I'm trying to add them together.

```
NSString *checkAmount = [checkAmountInput.text substringFromIndex:1];
NSDecimalNumber *checkAmountValue = (NSDecimalNumber*)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",checkAmount];
NSLog(@"%@", checkAmountValue);

NSString *bankBalance = [bankBalanceInput.text substringFromIndex:1];
NSDecimalNumber *bankBalanceValue = (NSDecimalNumber*)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",bankBalance];
NSLog(@"%@", bankBalanceValue);

NSDecimalNumber *totalAmount = 

NSLog(@"%@",totalAmount);
```

When I try using decimalNumberByAdding I get:

```
'-[__NSCFString decimalNumberByAdding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a39a10'
```

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong... but I'm just starting out again.

Comment: Besides the real issues, please do not needlessly make use of `stringWithFormat:`. `checkAmount` is already an `NSString`. Creating a new string using `stringWithFormat:` is two extra levels of incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `checkAmountValue` and `bankBalanceValue` aren't actually `NSDecimalNumber` instances. Casting an `NSString` to an `NSDecimalNumber` will silence a compiler warning, but the objects are still just strings.

You can use `decimalNumberWithString:` to create an actual `NSDecimalNumber` instance from a string:

```
NSString *bankBalance = [bankBalanceInput.text substringFromIndex:1];
NSDecimalNumber *bankBalanceValue = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:bankBalance];
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the issue with the decimalNumberByAdding issue I was getting. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's some mixed up code there. Effectively, what you want to do is grab the text from two `NSTextFields`, and convert them to `NSDecimalNumbers` and add them. You can certainly do that. Be aware that `NSTextField`, can also 'parse' the string value directly and return you a numeric type (int, double, float) directly:

```
double d = [textField doubleValue];
```

If you still wanted to use NSDecimalNumber, and parse it from an NSString:

```
NSString *s = [textField stringValue];
```

To convert the string to an NSDecimalNumber:

```
NSDecimalNumber *n1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:s]
NSDecimalNumber *n2 = // repeat as above for the second string
```

To add them together:

```
NSDecimalNumber *n3 = [n1 decimalNumberByAdding:n2];
```

Note that, `decimalNumberWithString` is a class factory method which creates an instance of `NSDecimalNumber` by parsing a string. In your case you were simply casting to this which really doesn't create the type that you need.

Comment: A `double` or `float` is not as precise as `NSDecimalNumber` and usually not a good idea if you're dealing with financial data.

Comment: Agree, that is why I still showed him how to convert the string values to NSDecimalNumber.

Comment: Since this is an iOS question, we are dealing with `UITextField`, not `NSTextField`. `UITextField` does not have `doubleValue` or `stringValue` methods.